# Python Unittest main function call returns wrong array

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am sitting in front of this problem for the last 2 hours and can't figure out what the problem is. I have a function which calculates something based on csv input. When I print the `"spalte_ideal_sammlung"` out of the function it returns the correct array: `['y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33']` but when I try to call these functions via my `unittest` I get this array as a return from the function: `['y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33', 'y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33']`. Any idea why I get this return instead of the correct one with 4 strings inside? The variable `spalte_ideal_sammlung` has been defined as global in my main function in the `main.py`.

```
def main():  # Mittels unsere Main-Funktion rufen wir die definierte Funktion auf


    global spalte_ideal_sammlung #Abspeichern unserer gefundenen idealen Spalten
    spalte_ideal_sammlung = []
```

My function in my `main.py`:

```
class LeastSquare(Berechnung):  # Klasse LeastSquare erbt von Berechnung
    # Überschreibe die Methode least_square_berechnung aus der Basisklasse Berechnung
    def least_square_berechnung(self):
        #pass
        # Initialisiere eine Liste, die später die LS-Werte für die Idealen-Funktionen enthält
        ls_ideal = []
        # Initialisiere eine Liste, welche die Spaltenbezeichnung für die Y-Werte der Trainingsdaten enthält. Die erste Spalte enthält die x-Werte.
        trainingsdaten = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"]
        # Wir starten ab der zweiten Spalte, weil ab hier die y werte liegen. Erste Spalte sind die X-Werte
        for columns_train in training.columns[1:]:
            mse = 9999
            # Durchlaufe alle Spalten der Idealen-Funktionen
            for columns_ideal in ideal.columns[1:]:
                #Berechnung MSE
                mse_zw = (mean_squared_error(training[columns_train], ideal[columns_ideal]))
                if mse_zw < mse:
                    mse = mse_zw
                    spalte_ideal = ideal[columns_ideal].name
            # Gefundene Werte werden ans Array übergeben.
            # Da der MeanSquaredError nicht dem verlangten SquaredError entspricht, überführen wir diesen durch den Faktor 400 in Wert der gesuchten Abweichung.
            ls_ideal.append(mse * len(ideal))
            spalte_ideal_sammlung.append(spalte_ideal)

        for i, y, k in zip(ls_ideal, spalte_ideal_sammlung, trainingsdaten):
            print("Für den Trainingsdatensatz " + str(k) + " lautet der LeastSquare " + str(
                i) + " die Ideale Funktion lautet " + str(y))

        return spalte_ideal_sammlung
```

I call the function out of my `unittes.py` (I did not start with the unit test because the return is not what I expected. Its definitely my fault but I can't find the mistake:

```
import unittest
import main

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):

        instanz1 = main.LeastSquare()
        print(instanz1.least_square_berechnung())
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: seems you are creating a new instance of `LeastSquare`
try passing the instance of `LeastSquare` to your unit test
 `self.assertEqual(instanz1.least_square_berechnung(), ['y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33'])`

Comment: @Samuel yes but when i print the instanz1.least_square_berechnung it returns the "wrong" array with 8 strings inside.

Comment: could be problem with calling the list more than once which causes it to append more than once in your instance

you could add this and check if it works

`main.spalte_ideal_sammlung = []
 self.assertEqual(instanz1.least_square_berechnung(), ['y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33'])`

Comment: @Samuel you are right! That definetly works! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: il rewrite in answer so you can accept :D

Comment: @Samuel thank you! Maybe I will find out why that problem appears but this quick fix is fine for the moment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be problem with calling the list more than once which causes it to append more than once in your instance you could add this and check if it works

```
main.spalte_ideal_sammlung = []
self.assertEqual(instanz1.least_square_berechnung(), ['y36', 'y11', 'y2', 'y33'])
```